# Set of JSON object as HTTP response - NodeJS

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I extract from MySQL a set of users' information and I serialize them in JSON. For example I have:

```
{"ID":1,"Username":"aaa","Email":"aaa@live.it","Password":"123456789"}
{"ID":2,"Username":"bbb","Email":"bbb@live.it","Password":"123456789"}
{"ID":3,"Username":"ccc","Email":"ccc@live.it","Password":"123456789"}
{"ID":4,"Username":"ddd","Email":"ddd@live.it","Password":"123456789"}
```

My target is to pass this set of JSON object in a NodeJS response.
I have tried something like this:

```
app.get('/getUsers', function (req, res) {

    var result = "";
    var JSONResult = "";
    var users="";


    connection.query('SELECT * FROM USER ORDER BY ID', function (err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) {

            console.log('There was an error\n' + err);

        }

        else {

            for (var i in rows) {
                result = rows[i];
                JSONResult = JSON.stringify(result);
                users = users + JSONResult;

            }

            console.log(users);
        }
    });


    res.json({ 'data': users});
    res.end(users);
});
```

But in this way my response is `data:""`.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely doing it wrong way. do not  stringily  and append into string. because then the result (**users**)string is not as per JSON syntax.

So just create array of users. and stringify it at the end.

also I guess you are passing users agains in res.end(). I guess thats duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already being returned an array of user objects. Why not just render that?

```
app.get('/getUsers', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM USER ORDER BY ID', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) return console.log('There was an error\n' + err);

        res.json({ data: users });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the `res.send` function call is outside the promise. Thus, `res.json({ 'data': users })` is called before the query have time to finish.

```
app.get('/getUsers', function (req, res) {
    var result = "";
    var JSONResult = "";
    var users="";

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM USER ORDER BY ID', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('There was an error\n' + err);
        }
        else {
            for (var i in rows) {
                result = rows[i];
                JSONResult = JSON.stringify(result);
                users = users + JSONResult;
            }
            console.log(users);
            res.status(200).send({ 'data': users});
        }
    });
});
```

I hope that it helps :]

https://github.com/billykong/active-serializer

I would also recommend using a json serializer for the response. The object we retrieve from the database aren't always in the format in which we want to send back. Sometimes, we may want to mask certain fields or other fields.